# Como fazer o python selecionar o maior número de um conjunto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde,
estou inputando números no python, mas não sei como fazer para agregá-los a um conjunto e depois fazer o python decidir qual é o maior número na lista.

Grato

Comment: Oi Bem vindo, mostro como vc está fazendo, tem alguma parte do código ? assim podemos te ajudar melhor...

Comment: Vou escrever um código como exemplo, assim fica mais fácil
pessoas = 5
respostas = 0
while respostas < pessoas:
        idade = int(input("Insira a idade da pessoa")
depois disso, eu queria guardar cada idade inputada em um conjunto e depois printar a maior delas, mas não sei como.

Comment: Veja minha resposta. Acho que é exatamente isso.

Comment: a quantidade de numeros inputados é pré definida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Levando em consideração somente inteiros (vc pode adaptar para outros tipos):

Versão com for:

```
lista = []
qtn = input('informe a qt de numeros: ')

for n in range(0,int(qtn)): 
    lista.append(int(input('Digite o número: ')))

print ('Maior número da lista: ', max(lista))
```

Versão com while:

```
lista = []
while True:
    n = int(input('Digite o número (0 para encerrar): '))
    if n == 0:
        break
        lista.append(n)

print ('O maior número da lista é: ',max(lista))
```

[Versão com for...](https://repl.it/HOVT/1)
[Versão com while...](https://repl.it/HOXx/0)

Comment: Obrigado, mas esqueci de avisar que como é exercicio de faculdade, não posso usar for pq nós não aprendemos ainda haha

Comment: É só trocar po while, como vc fez no exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado

Comment: Fiz uma nova versão, vou editar a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Estou começando agora em python, mas percebi que o loop while estaria correto se fosse escrito assim:

> ```
> lista = []
> while True:
>     n = int(input('Digite o número (0 para encerrar): '))
>     lista.append(n)
>     if n == 0:
>         break
>
>
> print ('O maior número da lista é: ',max(lista))*
> ```

Desculpe se mencionei algo errado.

Comment: Ao postar uma resposta, deve-se fazer com convicção (mesmo errando). Respostas como "tente", "eu acho", "talvez", "pode ser" não são respostas concretas e estão sujeitas a serem excluídas ou ganhar votos negativos.

Comment: ok obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = []
while len(lista) < 5:
    lista.append(input("Digite 5 numeros: "))
print "Maior numero: ", max(lista)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lista = []
while len(lista) < 5:
    n = int(input('Digite o número (0 para encerrar): '))
    lista.append(n)

print ('O maior número da lista é: ',max(lista))
```